# node.js net.socket client receiving bitmap (.bmp) images

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, socket.io

I'm developing a node.js application that needs to receive .bmp images from a photo sensor (essentially a camera) over tcp sockets. This camera post images in either a manual trigger or continuous (several frames per second) mode depending on the setup.

I have something working, though not an ideal solution, using net.sockets. I say not ideal, because I'm getting noisy images, occasionally a corrupt image, and sometimes miss an images all together. I know its not the camera because we already have a .net solution that acquires images reliably and with high fidelity. The difference being the .net solution polls the sensor on a timer, and where net.sockets is asynchronous event based.

The camera firmware is designed such that for each image it posts a 64 byte header describing the image (size in bytes, width, height, type, version, etc). Using the information in the header I know what's coming next. At this time I don't really have any latitude to change the way the camera is supplying the images. Perhaps in the future once I prove something is possible with the current firmware.

I'm new to node.js and am looking for a better solution. Eventually I'd like to be able to post the received images over socket.io for an AngularJS client to display. For now, getting high fidelity images reliably and writing them to disk will suffice.

Here's the code I currently have working:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
let net = require('net');
let fs = require('fs');
//let stream = require('stream'); //will likely need this

let client = new net.Socket();

const IMAGE_HEADER_SIZE = 64;
const IMAGE_PREFIX_SIZE = 16;

let headerImageSizeBytes = 0;
let headerImageFrameNumber = 0;
let imageBytesNeeded = 0;
let imageByteCount = 0;
let bytesAvailable = 0;
let bytesRead = 0;

client.connect(32200, '192.168.0.20', function () // 2MP
{
    //client.bufferSize = 100;        // Doesn't seem to work
    client.setNoDelay(true);
    console.log('connected');
});

client.on('data', function (buffer) {

    // Do we have a header frame?
    if (buffer.length == 64) {
        // Process that header
        console.log(bytesRead == 0 ? 
             "Acquiring next image" : 
             "Last Image Bytes read = " + bytesRead);
        bytesRead = 0;
        headerImageSizeBytes = 0;

        // Parse the header (Don't need 1st 16 Prefix bytes at this time)
        var offset = IMAGE_PREFIX_SIZE;
        headerImageSizeBytes = buffer.readUInt32LE(offset += 4);
        headerImageFrameNumber = buffer.readUInt32LE(offset += 4);
        imageBytesNeeded = headerImageSizeBytes;
        return;
    }

    // Collecting image bytes
    bytesRead += buffer.length;
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        imageByteCount = bytesRead;

        // TODO: Eventually going to need base64 to render as HTML image via Socket.io
        fs.appendFile('c:/temp/_IMG_FOLDER/image' 
            + headerImageFrameNumber + '.bmp', buffer, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });
        console.log("\t\t" + buffer.length);
    }
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Any suggestions for how to do this in a fast, efficient and reliable manner would be greatly appreciated.

And if your feeling up to it, an example of how to prepare the image to post to my AngularJS client for display as an image source.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nary a peep from the community, so I'll answer my question with the solution I came up with using a state machine to process the header and then fall into a state of capturing the described image. This solution produces high quality images with very decent reliability (i.e. fewer missed images).

'use strict';

```
let net = require('net');
let fs = require('fs');

let client = new net.Socket();

const IMAGE_HEADER_SIZE = 64;
const IMAGE_PREFIX_SIZE = 16;
const STATE_INIT = 0;
const STATE_DATA = 1;
let state = STATE_INIT;
let imageData;
let imageOffset = 0;


let headerImageSizeBytes = 0;
let headerImageFrameNumber = 0;
let imageBytesNeeded = 0;
let bytesRead = 0;

client.connect(32200, '192.168.0.20', function ()
{
  client.setNoDelay(true);
  console.log('connected');
});


client.on('data', function (buffer) {
  switch (state) {

    case STATE_INIT:

      // Ideally we'd have a more robust test here, i.e. consider scenario 
      // where header and image data arrive in same buffer
      if (buffer.length !== 64) {
        console.error('unexpected data received (bytes: ' + buffer.length + ')');
        return;
      }

      console.log(bytesRead == 0 ?
        "Acquiring next image" :
        "Last Image Bytes read = " + bytesRead);
      bytesRead = 0;
      headerImageSizeBytes = 0;

      // Parse the header (Don't need 1st 16 Prefix bytes at this time)
      var offset = IMAGE_PREFIX_SIZE;
      headerImageSizeBytes = buffer.readUInt32LE(offset += 4);
      headerImageFrameNumber = buffer.readUInt32LE(offset += 4);
      imageBytesNeeded = headerImageSizeBytes;
      imageData = Buffer.alloc(imageBytesNeeded)
      imageOffset = 0;
      state = STATE_DATA;
      break;

    case STATE_DATA:
      imageOffset += buffer.copy(imageData, imageOffset);
      if (imageOffset >= imageBytesNeeded) {
        fs.appendFile('c:/temp/_FTP_FOLDER/image' + headerImageFrameNumber + '.bmp', imageData, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
          }
        });
        state = STATE_INIT;
      } // else continue acquiring image until all bytes received
      break;
  }
});

client.on('end', function () {
  console.log('Transimission end');
});

client.on('close', function () {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Thanks to my [Intertech](http://www.intertech.com/) collegue @ryanharvey for his suggestion to use the state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but new solution:

```js
const cp = require('child_process'),
            fs = require('fs');

let idx = 0,
        ffmpeg = cp.spawn("ffmpeg", [
            "-re",
            "-y",
            "-i",
            "rtsp://192.168.1.139/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=00&authbasic=YWRtaW46Y2FtYXJhNHlvdQ==",
            "-preset",
            "ultrafast",
            "-f",
            "image2pipe",
            "pipe:1"
        ]);

ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    fs.writeFile('test-' + (idx++) + '.bmp', data, function(err) {
        console.log('Write frame!', err, data.length);
    });
});
```